# airflow scheduler how to config checking new files interval?

Tags: airflow

when I run the airflow scheduler on the server I found the scheduler are checking new dags file every 300 seconds.

```
Checking for new files in /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags every 300 seconds
```

how can I change this behavior cause I can't find any config in the aiflow.cfg to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under the `[scheduler]` section as `dag_dir_list_interval`.

```
# How often (in seconds) to scan the DAGs directory for new files. Default to 5 minutes.
dag_dir_list_interval = 300
```

Source: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.10.1/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L438-L439

Comment: I saw it yesterday, but thanks for your help.Also I find the airflow scheduler use lots of cpu time,  any way to reduce cpu usage?